# Text heavy iOS App. Store text in HTML, Plist, or Other?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, core-text

I'm writing relatively complex iOS app that is very text heavy.

The text is also heavily formatted. It has lots of color, size, font, and spacing changes, as well bulleted lists and other text features you'd expect to see in a very rich website.

The text is displayed on about 40 different views. Some of which display a lot of text, others a little. There is no one template that all the pages follow. (There are some that are similar, but that's not the point.)

Lastly, the text is constantly being changed and updated by an editorial team during development, not so much after release. The text has to be stored on the device, downloading files is not an option.

**My question is, what is the best way to store and then render all this text in an iOS App?**

---

## My approach

Store all the text content and formatting info in an html file and use

`[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:htmlDoc
                                     options:@{ 
             NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType} 
                          documentAttributes:&attrDict 
                                       error:&error];`

to create a NSAttributed string and use that to populate UITextViews.*

*Note: I would do some more work before creating the UITextViews. First I would parse it to find the appropriate page number [[Page:1.3]] and then parse the elements in that section [[header]], [[side_scroller]], etc...

I like this approach for two main reasons:

1. It created a separate copy document that contained all the text
   and formatting info.
2. I'm the only iOS developer, but we have a couple front-end
   developers. So when we get slammed with changes that need to be done
   in 3.45 minutes, I could have some of the guys help me make the
   changes, without having to know all the nuances of UIFont and
   related classes. Occasionally, the editors could even make the
   changes themselves :)

Minor reasons for liking this approach:

- The text can vary so much per page, that creating a new UIFont + Plist entry to store the formatting info seems like a bigger pain than having everything in a .html document. (I could be wrong about this.)
- Project managers will inevitably say: "Make this word a little bigger," "This word looks strange, add italics," and "Make everything purple!" HTML/CSS seems like a more flexible solution for quickly implementing these requests.

Downsides of this approach:

1. NSAttributedString picks up 99% of the HTML attributes I threw at it. It did not pick bullet spacing changes in unordered lists `<ul>`.
2. Plists are more performant.

Here are some other approaches I considered:

1. Plist + UIFont
2. RTF Document - Originally started with this, but found it hid a lot of what was going on and NSAttributedString wouldn't pick up some of the changes.
3. XML

Any advice or input would very appreciated.

Notes:
iPad app, 
iOS 7, 
No Internet Connectivity, 
Xcode 5

Comment: If the text is easily expressed as html (and style as CSS) you can open a UIWebView on a local file.  You can one big file with anchor links or many small ones.  UIWebView can be framed like any subview, and scrolling can be disabled.

Comment: If you need something that looks like HTML+CSS, use HTML+CSS. Other approaches will be a gigantic nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to store styled text in an iOS app was to write a Mac OS command line tool that opens RTF files and converts them to attributed strings (It's a 1-line call in Mac OS, but not supported in iOS for some reason.) I then use NSCoding to save the attributed strings as binary data, with a special .DATA filetype.

I created a custom UITextView category with a method that knows how to load the text view's attributed text from my custom filetype.

I created a build rule in my project that treats RTF files as source files in a build step and the .DATA filetype as the output, and copies the .DATA files into the build project.

Now, all I have to do is add an RTF file to my project the build process inserts the .DATA version of the styled text into the executable.

The Xcode editor knows how to edit RTF files, so you can edit them right in place in the IDE, **OR** you can edit them in TextEdit or any editor that supports RTF files.

There are a few things you can put in an RTF that aren't supported in UITextViews. (I don't remember what those are offhand. Sorry.)

I find styled WYSIWYG text much easier to deal with than HTML. You just edit the text, and the build process picks up the changes.

It worked beautifully. Plus, binary NSCoding output is a whole lot more compact than HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using web view. It can open files in resource bundle.

You can disable all the links in HTML by implementing delegate method shouldStartLoadWithRequest to return NO.

You might also want to set dataDetectorTypes to UIDataDetectorTypeNone.
That will disable auto link detection in web view